# SQL AGGREGATE PROBLEMS on Vertabelo academy

Tags: sql

I am currently working through Vertabelo SQL Training and I have run into an challenge that I for some reason cannot get passed!

Here is a link to the challenge https://academy.vertabelo.com/course/standard-sql-functions/string-functions/revision/numbers-revision

My code looks like this

```
SELECT c.name, c.level, SUM(c.hp+c.mp) AS points
FROM character c
GROUP BY c.name, c.level;
```

The error I am getting says that "column types or names do not match". Could this be a bug due to the fact this course specifically is in beta?

Comment: Vertabelo seems to be quite picky in this instance regarding column aliases. See my answer below for Vertabelo's "correct" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions, like SUM(), work on the column values for all rows together. What you want is probably simple addition. Try this:

```
SELECT c.name, c.level, c.hp+c.mp
FROM character c;
```

The Vertabelo app doesn't like column aliases.